# Cronjob function not executed - negative seconds

Tags: wp-cron, cron

I've created a custom function that read an XML file and import it in woocommerce products. The XML files are exported by an external platform every day in the website ftp.

I replaced the wordpress cronjob for a real cronjob, the cronjob actually calls the function but the function is never executed (see screenshot).

[image: XML cronjob]

My function:

```
<?php 
/**
 * DynamiX Child Theme Functions
 * Load languages directory for translation
*/ 

function XML_import() {
    $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'import_pw/';
    $files1 = scandir($dir);
    $files = array_diff($files1, array('.', '..'));



    foreach($files as $file) {
        $filename = $dir . $file;

        if (file_exists($filename))
        {
            $time = strtotime('2010-04-28 17:25:43');
            $time = filemtime($filename);

            $elapsedTime = time()-filemtime($filename);

            if( $elapsedTime < (24*3600) ) {
                $xml = simplexml_load_file($filename) or die ("Error, cannot create object");

                    foreach($xml->Machine as $Machine) {

                        if (!get_page_by_title($Machine->OMSCHR1, OBJECT, 'product')) :

                            // Empty array
                            $attributes = array();

                            if($Machine->BOUWJAAR != 0) {
                                // Bouwjaar Attribute
                                $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
                                $attribute->set_id(0);
                                $attribute->set_name('Bouwjaar');
                                $attribute->set_options(array($Machine->BOUWJAAR));
                                $attribute->set_position(1);
                                $attribute->set_visible(true);
                                $attribute->set_variation(false);
                                $attributes['bouwjaar'] = $attribute;
                            }

                            if($Machine->MERK != '') {
                                // Merk Attribute
                                $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
                                $attribute->set_id(0);
                                $attribute->set_name('Merk');
                                $attribute->set_options(array($Machine->MERK));
                                $attribute->set_position(0);
                                $attribute->set_visible(true);
                                $attribute->set_variation(false);
                                $attributes['merk'] = $attribute;
                            }

                            if($Machine->configuratie->NRR_1034 != '') {
                                // Brandstof Attribute
                                $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
                                $attribute->set_id(0);
                                $attribute->set_name('Brandstof');
                                $attribute->set_options(array($Machine->configuratie->NRR_1034));
                                $attribute->set_position(2);
                                $attribute->set_visible(true);
                                $attribute->set_variation(false);
                                $attributes['brandstof'] = $attribute;
                            }

                            if($Machine->URENST1 != 0) {
                                // Draaiuren Attribute
                                $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
                                $attribute->set_id(0);
                                $attribute->set_name('Draaiuren');
                                $attribute->set_options(array($Machine->URENST1));
                                $attribute->set_position(3);
                                $attribute->set_visible(true);
                                $attribute->set_variation(false);
                                $attributes['draaiuren'] = $attribute;
                            }

                            $description = '';

                            if($Machine->TYPE != '') {
                                $description .= 'Type: ' . $Machine->TYPE . '<br>';
                            }
                            if($Machine->MERKCODE != '') {
                                $description .= 'NO: ' . $Machine->MERKCODE . '<br>';
                            }
                            if($Machine->KENTEKEN != '') {
                                $description .= 'Kenteken: ' . $Machine->KENTEKEN . '<br>';
                            }
                            if($Machine->BOUWJAAR != 0) {
                                $description .= 'Bouwjaar: ' . $Machine->BOUWJAAR . '<br>';
                            }
                            if($Machine->URENST1 != 0) {
                                $description .= 'Urenstaat: ' . $Machine->URENST1 . '<br>';
                            }
                            if($Machine->configuratie->NRR_1034 != '') {
                                $description .= 'Brandstof: ' . $Machine->configuratie->NRR_1034 . '<br>';
                            }
                            if($Machine->configuratie->NRR_1093 != '') {
                                $description .= 'Hefvermogen: ' . $Machine->configuratie->NRR_1093 . '<br>';
                            }
                            if($Machine->configuratie->NRR_1035 != '') {
                                $description .= 'Hefhoogte: ' . $Machine->configuratie->NRR_1035 . '<br>';
                            }
                            if($Machine->configuratie->NRR_1026 != '') {
                                $description .= 'Voorzetapparatuur: ' . $Machine->configuratie->NRR_1026 . '<br>';
                            }
                            if($Machine->configuratie->NRR_1020 != '') {
                                $description .= 'Cabine: ' . $Machine->configuratie->NRR_1020 . '<br>';
                            }
                            if($Machine->configuratie->NRR_1008 != '') {
                                $description .= 'Extra hydrauliek ventielen: ' . $Machine->configuratie->NRR_1008 . '<br>';
                            }

                            $base64_img = $Machine->IMAGE;

                            // Upload dir.
                            $upload_dir  = wp_upload_dir();
                            $upload_path = str_replace( '/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $upload_dir['path'] ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

                            $img             = str_replace( 'data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $base64_img );
                            $img             = str_replace( ' ', '+', $img );
                            $decoded         = base64_decode( $img );
                            $filename        = $title . '.jpeg';
                            $file_type       = 'image/jpeg';
                            $hashed_filename = md5( $filename . microtime() ) . '_' . $filename;

                            // Save the image in the uploads directory.
                            $upload_file = file_put_contents( $upload_path . $hashed_filename, $decoded );

                            $attachment = array(
                                'post_mime_type' => $file_type,
                                'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $hashed_filename ) ),
                                'post_content'   => '',
                                'post_status'    => 'inherit',
                                'guid'           => $upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $hashed_filename )
                            );

                            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $hashed_filename );

                            var_dump($attach_id);

                            // Set woocommerce product
                            $getters_and_setters = array('name' => $Machine->OMSCHR1, 'slug' => $Machine->OMSCHR1, 'category_ids' => array(70),'description' => $description, 'image_id' => $attach_id, 'attributes' => $attributes);
                            $product = new WC_Product();
                            foreach ($getters_and_setters as $function => $value) {
                                $product->{"set_{$function}"}($value);
                            }

                            // Save product
                            $product->save();
                    endif;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Schedule Cron Job Event
function custom_cron_job() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'XML_import' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'XML_import' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'custom_cron_job' );
```

I added in my wp-config.php:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

Anyone that could help me? I'm stuck on this one.

Thanks.
Rens

Comment: If you disable WP Cron, you have to manually call it yourself, and do so for every site in a network, can you confirm the method you're using to do that? As well as the cron job itself, and identify the file in your question ( is it a standalone file? functions.php? A plugin? It's not clear )

Comment: Thanks for commenting!

I've set an real cronjob @ my hosting. the code i'm posting is the functions.php from a child theme.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix it!

The problem was calling the wrong add_action.

I had:

```
// Schedule Cron Job Event
function custom_cron_job() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'XML_import' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'XML_import' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'custom_cron_job' );
```

But it must be:

```
// Schedule Cron Job Event
if (! wp_next_scheduled( 'xml' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'xml' );
}

add_action( 'xml', 'XML_import' );
```